# What is an explanation for what the normalization for trainable optimizers do?

Tags: neural-networks, normalization

I was reading the paper [Optimization as a model for few-shot learning](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=rJY0-Kcll) and saw that they had a strange preprocessing step for their data/their gradients. To give context, that paper tries to train an optimizer and they treat the gradients as "data" (to avoid computing second order derivatives). They find that the size of these vary to much so they control their size with the following normalization equation:

[image]

Can someone explain to me what this normalization is doing? for the value of $p=10$, so $e^{-10}$, it seems it's always just taking the log and dividing by 10 because $e^{-10}$ is so tiny...It doesn't seem they actually pass the "real" gradients ever to the meta-learner. Is that true? Or am I missing something?